# How do I conda init if I don't have permission to edit my .bashrc file

Tags: bash, conda

I have installed miniconda3. `/full/path/to/bin/conda init -d` shows only my `.bashrc` will be modified. Is there a way to write the contents of `conda init` to a separate file called `init_conda.sh`, which can be sourced when required?

Comment: Yes, the only difference is that you should remember to source it. Better don't give it execute permission so if you try to run it fails.

Comment: What do you mean you don't have permission to modify your `.bashrc`? It's yours; of course you do. And changing it to source another file is no different from changing it to include the commands from the other file (though keeping things modular could be attractive for other reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can grab the actual code Conda would insert by adding a verbosity flag to the command:

```bash
/full/path/to/bin/conda init -d -v
```

And you can put that code (after removing the "+" that starting the lines, because it's a patch file output) in a file of your choice. Note that if you have a writable `~/.bash_profile`, that could be an alternative to `.bashrc`, and that would still be loaded by default in interactive bash sessions.

Another alternative is to use Conda's hardcoded initialization file. It should be found at:

```bash
${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

So, you might consider having an alias to source that, or create a softlink to it in a more memorable location.